# mvc3 custom model binder loads data from form, but the Base.BinModel clears the fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I created a custom binder that looks like this:

```
 public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {

            var o = new MetaObject();
            o.OnBinderLoad();
            o.StatusTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("StatusTypeId").AttemptedValue);
            o.Comments.setValue(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Comments").AttemptedValue);
            o.EffectiveDate.setValue(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("EffectiveDate").AttemptedValue);


           // bindingContext.ModelMetadata = 

            ModelBindingContext newBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
            {
                ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => o, typeof(MetaObject)),
                ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
                ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider



            };
            var returnValue = base.BindModel(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
            return returnValue;
        }
```

I run the debugger and the value of  o and newBindingContext.ModelMetadata  has the correct data before the call to base.BindModel. After that point Comments and EffectivDate are null.

How do I trace this and why would that happen.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you trying to bind to an object of type MetaObject? Or is that the MetadataType for the model object?

Comment: To the type MetaObject. The code above is used on many of my meta objects, but this is the only one that is 'removing' data after the base.bindmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was inheriting from DefaultBinder, the base.bindmodel was overriding what I did. I followed the example below and everything is binding correctly.

http://mgolchin.net/posts/20/dive-deep-into-mvc-imodelbinder-part-1